# html5 form field validation error on Safari 6 using Webshim

Tags: html, webshim

Required attribute is not working in Safari after using Webshim. I keep getting an error {"error": "Please use POST request"}.[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/nwD4Z/)

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
        <script src="js/polyfiller.js"></script>
        <script>jQuery.webshims.polyfill('forms');</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" required value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The path to the modernizr.src and your polyfiller.src are wrong. If I correct those. The example works in Safari 6 (here is a testlink: http://jsfiddle.net/nwD4Z/23/)

Comment: Thanks Alexander, appreciate the time taken in writing the solution.